# In Android is it possible to create an array of strings and LatLngs?

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to create maximum 6 line array of place names and LatLngs and then use an intent to send it to a map class where the user can select name. The name needs to still be tied to the LatLng so the map can centre and zoom to it.

I have added edited code below. I have a mix of putExtra and putParcelable as I'm trying anything to get a working prototype. Hopefully it makes some sense.

The Sending Class Geocode is this:

```
private void geocodeLocation(String gPlace) {
        Geocoder gGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try{
            List<Address> results = null;
            if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
                results = gGeocoder.getFromLocationName(gPlace, numberOptions);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            Iterator<Address> locations = results.iterator();
            String country;
            int opCount = 0; 
            while(locations.hasNext()){
                Address location = locations.next();
                raw += location+"\n";
                strAddressOutput[opCount] = location.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + location.getAddressLine(1) + country  + "\n";
                strLatOutput[opCount] = location.getLatitude();
                strLongOutput[opCount] = location.getLongitude();
                gLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                strLatLng[opCount] = gLatLng;
                opCount ++;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<opCount; i++){
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
        }
```

The Sending Class Intent is this:

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (!android.location.Geocoder.isPresent()) {
            return;
        }
        if (gAddressRequested) {

            geocodeLocation(gPlace); 

            Intent tdMap = new Intent(this, com.dm4_map_test.todos3maps.MainMap.class); 

            tdMap.putExtra(Constants.RETURNEDADDRESS, strAddressOutput); 

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(Constants.PLACE, gPlace);
            args.putParcelable(Constants.MAPCENTRE, gMapCentre);
            args.putParcelableArray(Constants.LATLNGS, strLatLng);
            tdMap.putExtra("bundle", args);

            startActivity(tdMap);
        }
    }
```

The Receiving Class is this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_map);

            MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                needsInit = true;
            }
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);  

        mPlace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txAddress);
        mAddressList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinAddressList);

        mPlace.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.PLACE));

        String[] recAddressAA = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(Constants.RETURNEDADDRESS); // NULLS from Geocoder?

        recAddressOutput = recAddressAA;

        String testAddressOutput = Arrays.toString(recAddressAA);

        Bundle bundleMapCentre = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
        mMapCentre = bundleMapCentre.getParcelable (Constants.MAPCENTRE);

        Bundle bundleLatLng = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
        LatLng[] mLatLng = bundleLatLng.getParcelableArrayList(Constants.LATLNGS); 

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainMap.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, recAddressOutput);  
        mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mAddressList.setAdapter(mAdapter); 

        });
    }
```

The line 'LatLng[] mLatLng = bundleLatLng.getParcelableArrayList(Constants.LATLNGS);' errors but I have stepped back to see if this a workable approach

Comment: the part about name tied to latlng make me thing on a hashmap you can receive the values and construct a hashmap with them in the map class.

Comment: One question: do you have the LatLongitudes values beforehand? What about the names? If so, you could store them in sqlite then simply pass an id of a particular location using intent extras instead of passing the entire object;

Comment: I have read some and seems that collection can be passed throught intents so you can have your hashmap and pass it in your intent.

Comment: The error is 'Incompatible types:   Required com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng[]         Found  java.util.ArrayList  <android.os.Parcelable>

Answer (score 0):

Intent lets you pass through ints, doubles, strings, etc. but if you want to pass a custom object you will have to create the custom object implementing `Parceable`. You can see a little bit about how to do that [here](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/04/passing-custom-objects-between-android.html)

Comment: LatLng can be sent in an intent as it already implements Parseable

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. I believe he will have to create a custom object to hold a LatLng and a Placename. He can pass an ArrayList of these objects through the intent using `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()`

Comment: He can do this with 2 ArrayLists. one ArrayList<String> and one ArrayList<LatLng>. They will maintain their order.

Comment: Hi tricknology, thanks for the input. How should I get and put the 2 ArrayLists?